# How to get NSFetchedResultsController to return relationships as sections for UITableViewController

Tags: core-data, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a NSManagedObjectEntity 'Event' which has date and location attributes and one-to-many relationships: alerts, reminders, goals.

How do I setup an NSFetchedResultsController so that i can display this in a UITableView.  Specifically, using the grouped dynamic table view with section headings:

- Section 0 - list date and location
- Section 1 - List all alerts
- Section 2 - List all reminders
- Section 3 - List all goals

I can return all the objects, but then I have to manually manage sections.  Is there a way, maybe for the sectionNameKeyPath of the NSFetchedResultsController to dynamically generate these sections containing the set of objects for each section so that I can use the methods from the documentation such as the `[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count]` method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Will all sections contain `Event` objects? Or is each section supposed to contain a different kind of object? This is not entirely clear from your question.

Comment: Sorry, one event on each view, but show the different relationships to the event in each section of the UITableViewController. e.g. So as above for one event, section 1 will list all the alert objects that have a relationship to that event.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use an `NSFetchedResultsController`'s sections like that. You will have to write custom logic.

Comment: Was starting to think as much.  Cheers for the confirmation